# Exceção com timestamp na base de dados

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

Quero inserir separadamente a hora e a data na base de dados, que têm os campos `timestamp` e `data`, respetivamente. E tenho o seguinte código para adicionar os campos:

```
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colaborador", Session["New"].ToString());
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Mas no entanto, fico sempre com a seguinte execeção a meio da inserção:

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT
>   with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a
>   DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

Estou a usar MS SQL Server 2012, numa base de dados na rede local.
O que estou a fazer de errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [tipo *timestamp* do SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms182776(v=sql.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é equivalente ao *rowversion*, ele não deve guardar um *timestamp* seu.

A solução está dada na mensagem de erro. Não grave nada nessa coluna. Para que gravar o `DateTime.Now` explicitamente se é exatamente isso que grava se deixar o SQL Server fazer por conta própria? Então a solução é só tirar a coluna da gravação e transferir isso para o SQL Server colocando `GetDate()` como `default`.

#### Se quiser usar seu próprio *timestamp*

Um *timestamp* é um número sequencial. Então tem que converter a data para um número atendendo o critério dele que começa em 01/01/1970. Não pode converter para um texto. Se quiser gravar um *timestamp*, use um campo `bigint` mesmo.

Para converter a data para o numérico compatível com *timestamp* pode fazer isto:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000
```

Ou pode criar um método de extensão se for fazer usar muito:

```
public static class DateTimeExt { 
    public static readonly DateTime TimeStampStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    public static long ToTimestamp(this DateTime value) => (long)(value - TimeStampStart).TotalSeconds;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eKJIpc). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nQRE7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/GetTimeStamp.cs).

Comment: +1 em solidariedade ao -1 sem motivo que recebeu.

Comment: Vai entender...

Answer (score 1):

Kawaii, se esat utilizando o MSSQL e quer armazenar um data e hora em campos distintos, aconselho que altere o tipo do campo para `date` e `time` respectivamente.

Em todo caso, para bancos novos, o aconselhavel é evitar o uso dos tipos `datetime` e `timestamp`, utilize os não tão novos tipos `date`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, `time`

```
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Date, 8).Value = DateTime.Today;
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.Add("@hora", SqlDbType.Time, 5).Value = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

caso não possa modificar a estrutura do banco de dados, você terá de se adequar à esta modelagem mal feita, no seu lugar eu faria o insert da data e hora no campo `data` e o `timestamp/rowversion` fornecido pelo sistema no campo `hora`.

neste caso o nome do campo não vai ser auto explicativo, inclusive o mesmo vai está descaracterizado, mas se fizer de outra forma, você vai está descaracterizando o tipo do dado, e entre manter a semantica do nome da coluna e do tipo de dados, prefiro a do tipo.

```
SqlCommand sqlInsertCabecalho = 
new SqlCommand("Insert into cabecalho (nRequesicao,nomeEmpresa,colaborador,data,nota) VALUES(@nRequesicao,@nomeEmpresa,@colaborador,@data,2nota)", sqlConn);

sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.Add("@nRequesicao", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = nRequesicao; // estou assumindo que está utilizando um campo int
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.Add("@nomeEmpresa", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = DropDownListEmpresa.Text; // estou assumindo que está utilizando um campo varchar(50)
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.Add("@colaborador", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Session["New"].ToString(); // estou assumindo que está utilizando um campo varchar(50)
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value = DateTime.Now;  // estou assumindo que está utilizando um campo datetime
sqlInsertCabecalho.Parameters.Add("@nota", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = Session["New"].ToString());  // estou assumindo que está utilizando um campo varchar(10)
```

mas o meçhor é que procure o administrador do banco de dados e sugira a modificação dos tipos, desta forma a seguir as recomendações da propria Microsoft.:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: Para poder modificar os tipos preciso de pedir permissões à administração daqui, não existe mesmo outro maneira?

Comment: como o bigown mesmo disse, o tipo `timestamp` apesar de iniciar com o termo `time` não serve para uma hora, no seu caso, como acredito que o campo `data` é do tipo `datetime`, talvez seja melhor você inserir data e hora nele... e deixar que o proprio SQLServer insira o valor default no campo do tipo `timestamp`.